# Under what condition does Dalton's law of partial pressure starts to fail?

Tags: pressure, gas

Imagine we have a sealed container with an equilibrium system in it, e.g. water/water vapor, ammonia/nitrogen/hydrogen, and we keep adding helium into the container, and maintain the temperature. Then at what point does the equilibrium start to shift?

Comment: Note: water vapor is water, but nitrogen and hydrogen are not ammonia.  It takes a chemical reaction to convert hydrogen and nitrogen into ammonia, but it only takes a phase change to convert water into water vapor.

Answer (score 1):

When one cannot neglect anymore the interactions between the molecules (at least the molecular collisions).

Dalton's law is based on the assumption of ideal gases, where the molecules do not interact - neither for different gases nor for the same gas. What fails at high densities is thus usually not the Dalton law per se, but the ideal gas law. [Van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) can be viewed as the lowest order attempt at fixing the ideal gas law to make it work.

Comment: can higher partial pressure by a neutral inert gas, say, $He$ induce (catalyze?) chemical reaction between otherwise nonreacting gasses at some fixed temperature such as $H_2$ and $O_2$? (Assume that the process of increasing the pressure is isothermal.)

Comment: @hyportnex I don't think this is directly related to the question - chemical reaction is just another means of changing pressure and temperature.